# Errors pertaining to the "!==" function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to make a program in Python that basically asks you math problems. For some reason, there's a lot of errors, and I have no idea why, such as the "!==" function, which seems to be incorrect. There might also be some other issues as I've only just started Python. Could someone direct me to how to use the !== function correctly and also my other issue: Making my input for "addition, subtraction, or multiplication" into a possible command?
# import random
import time
choice = 0
counterright = 0
counterwrong = 0

```
def add_question_to_file(a, b):
    with open("wrong_answers.txt", 'a') as f:
      f.write(f"{a} {operation} {b}\n")

def test(a,operation,b):
    user_input = int(input(f"{a} {operation} {b} = "))
    if user_input == a + b:
        print("You got it right!")
        counterright += 1 
    while user_input != a + b:
        if user_input == a + b:
            print("You got it right!")
            counterwrong += 1
            break
        else:
            add_question_to_file(a, b)
            print("Try Again!")
            user_input = int(input(f"{a} + {b} = "))

def get_question():
    a = random.randint(1, 10)
    b = random.randint(1, 10)
    with open("calc_log.txt", 'a') as f:
      if a<b: #insures a is always greater than b
        a, b = b, a
      f.write(f"{a} {operation} {b}\n")

def check_operation():
      if operation !==t "+" or "-" or "*"
        print("Sorry, that's invalid. You have to choose of the three operations!")

t1=time.perf_counter()  #

m = input("What mode would you like to use? Review/Normal. Choose Normal if this is your first time!")
operat ion = input("Which operation would you like to use? +,-,or *?")

if m == "review":
    with open("wrong_answers.txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            a, operation, b = line.split()
            test(int(a), int(b))
elif m == "normal":
    num_questions = int(input("How many questions would you like to do? "))
    for i in range(num_questions):
        print(f"You are on question {i + 1}: ")
        get_question()  

t2=time.perf_counter() #

print("It took you", t2-t1, "seconds for you to solve this problemset") #

print ("You got",counterright,"correct and",counterwrong,"wrong.")
```

Comment: != instead of !==

Comment: there is no `!==` function in python. There is a `!=` operator, which I guess is what you meant. The only language that has `!==` is javascript as far as I know.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, [PHP has `!==` too](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason !== isn't working is because this is not an operator in python. Try using !=. It means not equal too.

Answer (score -3):

The does not equal function in python is !=. The double equal sign (==) is only used when you want to check for equality. I hope this helps!